# Grant Permissions In Claims Based Authentication using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, claims-based-auth

We have a SharePoint which uses claims based authentication. I need to iterate through all files in library using PowerShell and share the each with a particular claim.

Could you please help me to to figure our how can I add a claim as a user/group in PowerShell considering the following scripts:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
$url = "http://mysite"
$listName = "mylist"
$permissionLevel = "read"
$groupName = "c:0-.f|rolesprovider|claim"
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$group = $web.EnsureUser($groupName) #Exception calling "EnsureUser" with "1" argument(s): "The specified user could not be found."
$role = $web.RoleDefinitions[$permissionLevel]
$assignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)
$assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($role)
foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
        $item.RoleAssignments.Add($assignment)
        $item.Update()
    }
}
$web.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Programmatically granting permissions to claims](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-granting-permissions-claims/)

Comment: The article is useful, but the question was about how to do this with PowerShell... Can you improve your answer adding a relevant code sample? It will also be better than just referencing external site.